# put: unexpected URISyntaxException

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to put timestamp appended file name in HDFS?

`hadoop fs -put topic_2018-12-15%2016:31:15.csv /user/file_structure/`

Answer (score 0):

You're just running a shell command, so you can use command evaulation

For example, to rename a file to have `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
hadoop fs -put \
    'topic_2018-12-15%2016:31:15.csv' \
    "/user/file_structure/topic_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).csv"
```